# Creating a duplicate of a VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm preparing to get in to the world of cloud computing.

My first question is:

Is it possible to programmatically create a new, or duplicate an existing VM from my server?

**Project Background**

I provide a file processing service, and as it's been growing I need to offer a better service.

**Project Requirement**

Machine specs:

> HDD: Min 16gb
>
> CPU: Min 1 core
>
> RAM: Min 2
>
> GB GPU: Min CUDA 10.1 compatible

What I'm thinking is the following steps:

- User uploads a file
- A dedicated VM is created for that specific file inside Google Cloud Compute
- The file is sent to the VM
- File is processed using a Anaconda environment
- Results are downloaded to local server
- Dedicated VM is removed
- Results are served to user

How is this accomplished?

PS: I'm looking for resources and advice. Not code.

Comment: 1) Create a VM, install your apps, tools, files, etc. 2) Create an Image of the VM. 3) Now you can launch a VM built from the image with `gcloud` or using the SDKs/APIs very easily. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/images/create AND https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance

Comment: How many instances of the same VM can I spin up simultaneously?

Comment: As many as your quota allows. I think the default is 8 total cores across all VMs. You can request a quota increase in the Google Cloud Console.

Comment: @JohnHanley as I am new to this and you probably know more than me, I'll try to reformulate my question just to make sure that I used the correct terminology;
Can I create a VM, and duplicate that VM multiple times so that, say, 5 of the same VM is running in parallel?

Comment: Directly no. By creating an image first, yes. Google also has the ability to "create more instances like this one" in the Google Cloud Console. If you want to do so programmatically (via API), read the links I provided.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a **perfect** formulation of the concept of Google Cloud Run.  At the highest level concept, you create a Docker image (think of it like a VM) and then register that Docker image with GCP Cloud Run.  When a *trigger* occurs, GCP will spin up an instance of that Docker container and pass in information about the cause of that trigger (a file created in GCS or a REST request or others ...).  What you do in your container is up to you.  You have full power of the Linux environment (under Docker) to do as you like.  When your request ends, the container is *spun down*.  You are *only* billed for the compute resources you use.  If your container (VM) isn't being used, you pay nothing until the next trigger.

An alternative to Cloud Run is Cloud Functions.  This is a higher level abstraction where instead of providing a Docker container, you provide the body of a function (JavaScript, Java, Python or others) and the request is passed to that function when a trigger occurs.  Which you use is mostly personal choice (you didn't elaborate on "File is processed").

References:

- [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/)
- [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/)

Comment: Nice. I edited the question in the "- File is processed".
Basically, I can set up a VM with all the files and scripts needed, and then initiate an instance of that VM?

Comment: I'm getting the sense that your goal is to have a server that services requests.  I'm assuming you don't want to be billed when there is no work for it.  Are you familiar with containerization technologies (Docker)?  I'm still of a mind that Cloud Run is still a worthy candidate.  This falls into the technology domain known as "serverless".  The notion being you bring the docker container that encapsulates your application and GCP (Cloud Run) owns the lifecycle of that container and calling it when work needs done.

Comment: Yes that is correct. I do not need the Google Cloud VM to run if there is nothing to process.
Unfortunately I am not familiar with docker, however the Anaconda environment that will process the file can also be executed via docker.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are a programmer or a data analyst or something else.  There is school of thought that says eventually everyone will need some fundamental containerization skills and this may be a good time to wrestle some docker.  It isn't awful.

Comment: @vaid - The best answer requires more details. For example, how much CPU power do you need? Memory, temporary disk storage? How long does the task run?

Comment: @JohnHanley ofcourse. My bad. I updated the question again with included minimum specs.

Comment: @Kolban I guess a little bit of both, but more of a programmer. However, no project has required me to do any cloud related computing up until now.